# Applications interested to the same event and concurrency

Tags: c#, event, rabbitmq

I have an event pubblished in a bus(rabbit) and two application that are subscribed to this Event.

```
public class CreationEvent 
{
    public int CreationEventID {get; set; }
    ... other properties
}
```

Application A and Application B are subscribed to this event, and listen from a rabbit queue.
Application A save the properties of this event in its database.

Application B save the properties of this event in its database. In addition create another event related to the CreationEventId with other properties and send it to a rabbit queue

```
public class ExtendCreationEvent
{
    public int ExtendCreationEvent {get; set; }
    public int CreationEventID {get; set; }
    ... other properties
}
```

Application A is subscribed to this Event and listen from a rabbit queue, read and save the properties in its database related to
CreationEventID.

This is the problem. I don't know if the Application B is too fast and pubblish the event ExtendCreationEvent before ApplicationA save CreationEventID from the first event. So application A could try to elaborate event ExtendCreationEvent before the elaboration of CreationEvent .

How can I solve this problem and guarantee the elaboration  order in Application A?

Comment: It is not clear to me how this relates to .NET events. Perhaps it doesn't. It sounds like you  are calling directly into application code with this and this is the problem. Try posting to a queue instead and let the receiving application deal with the message when it is ready to do so.

Comment: Hi Martin. I've rephrased the question, I hope it's more clear. The applications doesn't call directly each other. They communicate only with events on a rabbit queue.

Comment: user3401335 If there is such a strong dependency (B needing results of A), why not have A do the extended stuff in sequence? Or, have A post an event to B when it's ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rarely guarantee the execution order of anything concurrent; therefore, the obvious solution although not necessarily satisfying is to sequence the operations. Some suggestions to do that:

Chain the event:

Application A is the only subscribed to the Creation Event. Application B waits A to emit a Created Event to it, that A will when its processing is fully complete.

Submit to the original queue, single worker:

Application A and B listen to events. A gets Creation event. B completes its processing and publish to the same queue the ExtendCreationEvent. Since A is currently processing Creation event it doesn't process ExtendCreationEvent before finishing CreationEvent.

Push back:

A and B listen to events. A get ExtendCreationEvent, check for existence of the CreationEvent in database. If not, push back the event in the queue / retry after a timer

Answer (score 3):

Let me quickly rephrase your question to make sure I am understanding correctly.

You have two applications, `App_A` and `App_B`.
They both subscribe to the same message, `CreationEvent`.

When `App_B` gets the `CreationEvent` message is does some stuff with the message and then publishes a new `ExtendedCreationEvent` message.

`App_A` subscribed to both the `CreationEvent` and `ExtendedCreationEvent` messages. But you do not want `App_A` to process a `ExtendedCreationEvent` message until the associated `CreationEvent` message is processed.

Let me know if I've misunderstood any of that.

---

Here are two options for you.

1. have `App_B` fail to process a `ExtendedCreationEvent` unless it sees the associated `CreationEvent` in the database. If a `ExtendedCreationEvent` is received but no matching `CreationEvent` can be found in the database you should requeue the message for processing later.
2. Place all `CreationEvent`s and `ExtendedCreationEvent`s on the same RabbitMq queue. Because RabbitMq queues are FIFO (first in first out, or "ordered") by default the `ExtendedCreationEvent` will never be able to "jump ahead" of the `CreationEvent`.

Each of the above options has caviats.

Option 1 will only work if every `ExtendedCreationEvent` has a matching `CreationEvent`.

Option 1 will either require you to configure the retry handling of your message bus to ensure that messages can be retried. Or will require you to write a re-publish message function for your code.

Option 2 depends heavily on the behavior of your message bus. It might not work for a non RabbitMq bus or a non-default configuration of your RabbitMq queue which does not guarantee FIFO.

Option 2 will also not work if you need to be able to retry failed messages. As this causes a reordering of messages.

Option 2 requires your message deserializer to be able to read both `CreationEvent` and `ExtendedCreationEvent`. Polymorphism at deserialization time can be tricky if the messages do not follow a common pattern.